Chrome "object" tag does NOT propagate the "dragover" event to the embedded Webpage
Other events like "dragstart" and "click" do propagate even in Chrome, but not "dragover".
It works perfectly well in Firefox, but unfortunately there are still people using this bugged malware-infected browser just because "it's google", so I have to find a solution. Any workarounds?
Update: it is not only "dragover" which is not forwarded to the embedded webpage, but also "dragenter", "dragleave" and "drop".
However, both "drag" and "dragend" events work, so it is possible to manually dispatch the other events. But that may be not easy in some cases (e.g. I have to keep the "touch" events in mind as well and they use the same dispatch-trick), prepare for a few wasted days, "thanks" to google, unbelievable how bad it has become in the last 15 years. First their search engine became useless trash, now their browser too.
Update2: since I can't upload .zip files here, here is the minimal example which works fine in FF, but doesn't work in Chrome.

create test.html



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div><object data="aaa/google.html " width="900" height="700" type="text/html"/></div>
  </body>
</html>




create new folder "aaa" and enter it
create google.html inside it



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <div id="container">
      <textarea id="txtarea" rows="5" ondragover="console.log('dragover')" ondragenter="console.log('dragenter')" ondragleave="console.log('dragleave')" ondrop="console.log('drop'); return false"></textarea>
      <div id="buttons">
        <img id="google" src="google.jpg" draggable="true"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




create google.jpg inside it, I used this one https://i.sstatic.net/MBg6CRCp.jpg

Now open test.html, open developer console and try to drag the image on the text area.
What should happen and what happens in Firefox: you get all the messages ("dragenter", "dragover", "dragleave", "drop") and then since the default drop is cancelled by return, the text area remains empty.
What happens in Chrome: you get NONE of the messages and the text area is filled with the address of the image, which means that NONE of the events have been forwarded to the embedded webpage!

any way you could wrap the object with a div and use the div to handle all those events instead of the object?

It's already wrapped with a div, there was a reason for that, but it doesn't help by itself. Could you elaborate please? E.g. which event should be bound to div and/or object to properly forward the dragover to the underlying webpage? It's on another domain btw, I believe it matters.
Also since click and dragstart events are properly forwarded, I believe that in worst case scenario it should be possible to just write my own D&D based on simple pointer events? Sure I will need to detect where the mouse is and somehow draw a semi-transparent copy of the image, but that doesn't sound too hard.

actually I can't replicate. https://jsfiddle.net/nf52Lad6/1/ this seems to be working fine

Excuse me, maybe I wasn't clear enough, but my object tag has a "data" attribute, which points to the webpage, which contains the JS script, which does everything I want.

@DerekPollard I have written an extensive guide how to reproduce it, please take a look.

I can't get the HTML document in the <object> to work either.
Could you use an <iframe> as an alternative?


<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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" width="400" height="300"></iframe>



Here id the HTML document what I present in the iframe:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        const txtarea = document.getElementById('txtarea');

        txtarea.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
          e.target.value += 'dragover ';
        });
        txtarea.addEventListener('dragenter', e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.target.value += 'dragenter ';
        });
        txtarea.addEventListener('dragleave', e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.target.value += 'dragleave ';
        });
        txtarea.addEventListener('drop', e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.target.value += 'drop ';
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img width="50" height="50" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMCAxMCI+CiAgPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNSIgY3k9IjUiIHI9IjUiIGZpbGw9Im9yYW5nZSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+" draggable="true"/>
    <div id="container">     
      <textarea id="txtarea" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


I need object tag, iframe doesn't work on the platform I am using. It is a confirmed bug now https://issues.chromium.org/issues/360599252
Thanks for trying to help, will mark it as an answer.
